# Closure of a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ under addition and multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, field-theory

> Let $A$ be the set of real numbers of the form $A=\left\{\left. a+b\sqrt{2}\right|a \in \mathbb{Q}, b\in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$. Prove that if $x \in A$ and $y \in A$, then $x+y\in A$ and $xy \in A$.

I am taking my first proof writing class and having a hard time with this proof. Any hints, guidance, or answer would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $x\in A$ and $y\in A$, then $x=p+q\sqrt2$ and $y=r+s\sqrt2$ for some $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb Q$.  Now what's $x+y$ and $xy$?

Comment: You need to show some of your effort.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for this. From here, I found how to move forward with the proof. I appreciate your help and your comment

Comment: As such @Artek do you want to answer your own question?

Comment: By the way, $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$, but not $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be two elements of $\mathbb{A}$, they have to be written as follow:
$x=e+f\sqrt{2}$
$y=g+h\sqrt{2}$
with $e,f,g,h\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Now, $x+y=e+f\sqrt{2}+g+h\sqrt{2}=(e+g)+(f+h)\sqrt{2}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{A}$. Ideed, you have that $(e+g)\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $(f+h)\in \mathbb{Q}$ because they are sum of two numbers of $\in \mathbb{Q}$, that is close whit respect to the addition. So $x+y$ respects the conditions requested to stay in $\mathbb{A}$.
For $xy$ in the similar way: $xy=(e+f\sqrt{2})(g+h\sqrt{2})=(eg+2fh)+(eh+fg)\sqrt{2}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{A}$. Indeed $(eh+fg)\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $(eg+2fh)\in \mathbb{Q}$, because $\in \mathbb{Q}$ is closed with respect to the multiplication. So even $xy$ respects the conditions requested to stay in $\mathbb{A}$. So $\mathbb{A}$ is close under addition and multiplication as a consequence that $\mathbb{Q}$ is, too.